# How to fix without www to www htaccess canonical issue in SEO

Tags: .htaccess, seo

My website is hosted on an apache server at godaddy, I'm trying resolve `non-www` to `www` canonical issue, I added this code to .htaccess file with my domain name but its not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Hosting Server Details at Godaddy

Operating System : Linux

Server Type      : Apache

Hosting Configuration : 2.2

Please help me out to get rid of it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0):

The following should redirect all `non-www` pages to `www`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you do a hard refresh or try it on another browser?